# class icon in gridView column using VB.net

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, gridview

I have one GridView and I have a CSS class called `class="icon-p"`. I want to use this class in my GridView column "Modify", except using `ButtonType="Image"` and `ImageUrl`..`

Here is my GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       CssClass="table" DataKeyNames="id_s" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        ..
        <asp:CommandField CancelText="cancel" DeleteText="delete" EditText="Update" HeaderText="Modify" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True" ButtonType="Image"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Ok, I am confused what does the CSS class `icon-p` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your GridView in design view then go to edit columns.

Find the commandfield and click the blue hyperlink at the bottom that says "Convert to Template".

Exit back out and go to your markup and you will find that the individual controls are there and you can get at them to set your `CssClass` etc. The only thing that makes it an update button is the `CommandName="Update"` attribute.

This article here details the conversion steps that I was trying to explain:

- http://peterkellner.net/2009/09/06/detailsview-gridview-aspnet-disable-new-edit-delete-buttons/

You will then be left with something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Visible='<%# GetShowEditButton() %>'
                             CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                         &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Visible='<%# GetShowInsertButton() %>'
                             CommandName="New" Text="New"></asp:LinkButton>
                         &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                             CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" Visible='<%# GetShowDeleteButton() %>'     ></asp:LinkButton>
                     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can then set the CssClass like this for example:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
Visible='<%# GetShowEditButton() %>' CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"
CssClass="icon-p"></asp:LinkButton>
```